# AS3 - check if flv has video in it

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, netstream

I'm a n00b @ AS but I have managed to put together a video player using NetStream that suits my needs perfectly. The thing I'd like to add is that it would display a certain image if the streamed .flv clip only has audio track in it (mp3 converted flv).

Q: is there a way to check if the .flv I'm streaming has video in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I found the solution. Using info from "onMetaData" I can check for video codec (videocodecid) and it seems to return "undefined", if the .flv only contains audio.